# Open text file in browser tab in utf-8

Tags: tomcat, text, utf-8, character-encoding

There is this page where I give the user some links.
Every link targets a text file. When the user clicks
it just opens the text in the browser tab. 
How can I set the encoding to be utf8?
The files are in utf8 but not showing like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean text/plain files with .txt extension served by tomcat, you can

```
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>txt</extension>  
    <mime-type>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
```

In your web.xml

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. Thank you for your time